# retrieve a coupon in stripe using python

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project to create a subscription function for our products. I'm creating a function to check if the coupon code entered by the user matches the coupon.id in stripe if it does then it should store it in session else it should display "incorrect code" message. My code seems to be incorrect and is not working. Please help !!!

```
views.py

def retrieve_coupon(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CouponApplyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code = form.cleaned_data['code']
            try:
                coupon_id = stripe.Coupon.retrieve(code)
                request.session['coupon'] = code



            except coupon.DoesNotExist:
                messages.info(request, "This coupon does not exist")
                request.session['coupon'] = None
        context={
        'form':form
        }

    return render(request, "retrieve_coupon.html", context)
```

```
forms.py

class CouponApplyForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField()
```

```
template

<div class="divo">
    <p>
        coupon code to apply discount
    </p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        
        <input type="submit" value="apply" class="btn">
        <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than posting same question again and again, you should do some research on it, read the stripe documentation thoroughly, then ask a concrete question with proper error stacktraces and blockers you are facing.

Comment: @ruddra I have read the stripe documentation there's not enough information given and I have been searching on the internet for a while now nothing much about stripe coupons in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible issues:

```
import stripe # make sure this is imported and a python package
stripe.api_key = "SECRET_STRIPE_API_KEY" # Set the API key.
```

Known Error:

```
 coupon.DoesNotExist # is not valid
```

You need to properly handle exceptions as such:

```
try:
    coupon_id = stripe.Coupon.retrieve(code)
    request.session['coupon'] = code
except (stripe.error.RateLimitError,
    stripe.error.InvalidRequestError,
    stripe.error.AuthenticationError,
    stripe.error.APIConnectionError,
    stripe.error.StripeError,
    ) as e:
    request.session['coupon'] = None
    messages.info(request, "Error message")
```

If you have the stripe package, set an API Key, and create a coupon through Stripe this will work.

In regards to the down-votes, you should be getting an error like this: "NameError: name 'coupon' is not defined". Then you could ask the more specific question, how to handle stripe invalid requests, to which the answer is:

```
try:
    stripe.Coupon.retrieve("invalid_id")
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError:
    # handle error
```

If this is not the solution, then make sure you are using Stripe correctly. Are you making successful attempts?